# do I need to have played Watch Dogs 1 to understand Watch Dogs 2's storyline?

Tags: watch-dogs, watch-dogs-2

I didn't like the Watch Dogs 1 storyline all that much and I didn't quite like the cover-based shooting. The engine was also running somewhat poorly on my system. I own the game, but I never finished it.

Do I need to have played the Watch Dogs 1 storyline to understand the story line for the sequel? feel free to also comment on the other 2 problems I had with the game if you think the sequel won't satisfy me in that regard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't really have to. The basic storyline from the first game is glossed over in the introduction. Otherwise, you don't need to know the storyline of the old game.

The storyline of the sequel so far is much better from what I have played, and you don't need to even use a gun after the prologue stuff due to how the hacking system has improved.

Comment: I never used a gun in the first game either. That stun rod could knock anyone out in a single strike.

Comment: I like the stun gun of the second game. Same effect.